# Merging Two Pandas DataFrames on Year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes together but every time I try the merge I get the following message:

TypeError: merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'

```
d = {'year': [2001, 2002], 'wsp': [0.51, 0.42]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d2 = {'year': [2001, 2002], 'age': [50, 60]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
join = pd.merge([df, df2], on='year')
```

The output I'm trying to get is:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJBpk.png)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas merge two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035432/pandas-merge-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic idea down, just use one of the dataframes and the `.` method syntax to get the correct form:

`join = df.merge(df2, on="year")`

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use the concat function**

join = pandas.concat([df,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the parenthesis in the pd.merge.

```
d = {'year': [2001, 2002], 'wsp': [0.51, 0.42]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d2 = {'year': [2001, 2002], 'age': [50, 60]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
join = pd.merge(df, df2, on='year')
```

Output:

```
    wsp  year  age
0  0.51  2001   50
1  0.42  2002   60
```